Crystal Reports and how to handle it in .Net 8
I have a webforms project with quite a number of designed crystal reports. I have used slicing to slice the project up and move majority of the Logic to class libraries to make the migration easier. I however have the pain of these hundreds of designed crystal reports that I want to transfer to whatever else will work.
I am on M3 MacBook now, and windows 11 arm in parallels is giving me errors with crystal report so I want to use Rider. I just don’t know what to do with these reports and how to get them running. The reports directly goes to pdf when clicked or any other format (word, excel) a user prefers, and I use datasets mainly as the report data

Keep your Crystal-related dlls at .NET 4.8.
Later (AKA .NET Core) versions are not supported (due to COM dependencies in the Crystal runtime).
